# Trying to implement graph using array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, graph

I am trying to implement a graph using an array of vectors. I am having an incredibly difficult time doing so. The vectors will hold the vertices adjacent to the vertex v, which is an index of the array named uvertices.

This is what I have so far.

```
class Graph {


public:

    int V;          //this will represent the number of vertices in the graph

std::vector<int>* vertices;

 Graph(int V) {

    vertices = new std::vector<int>[V];

  }
```

Here, I have created (or think and meant to have created) an ARRAY of size V (V is the number of vertices in the graph) that holds vectors. I then want to be able to create edges, so I have

```
void Graph::insert_edge(int v, int u) {


}
```

as a method. I want to push_back the value u into the vector holding the adjacency list of vertex v.Each index of my array of vectors (named **vertices**) represents the identifier of each vertex v in the graph. So I want to do something like

```
  vertices[v].push_back(u);
```

I was surprised to find that when I typed vertices[v]., Intellisense gave me a list of possible functions, including push_back. The reason I was surprised was because I hadn't actually created any of the vectors, but I left it like this. This is obviously not working, so I started debugging, and I realized that whenever I first call insert_edge, it tells me the size and the capacity of my array "vertices" is 0. Despite the fact that I created my graph data structure as

```
Graph G(8);
```

I've spent about two hours trying to figure out how to work with this, and I am just not successful.

How do I Make it so that when an edge is inserted, I can look at the correct index v in the vertices array, and access the push_back function of the vector that that index of the array holds so that I can add the vertex u to the adjacency list of vertex v.

Also, I truly truly truly beg that if people give me downvotes or vote to close my topic, PLEASE let me know why. It can be so frustrating to spend time writing all of this out and making sure it's clearly written only to be voted down without anyone even telling me why they are voting me down.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `new std::vector<int>[V]` and not `new std::vector<int>(V)`?

Comment: @CompuChip Yes. I am dynamically creating an array that holds objects of type std::vector<int>

Comment: @FrostyStraw why do you want to manage the memory manually?

Comment: As @user2079303 implies, working with a vector of vectors would be easier that using an array of vectors.

Comment: @FrostyStraw ah I missed that you are creating an array of vectors. Confusing :)

Comment: @user2079303  Because otherwise I'd have to already have the size of the array that I'm creating beforehand. I wouldn't be able to input it as an argument to the array data structure

Comment: @FrostyStraw no, you don't already need to have the size in order to let a vector to handle the memory of the array. You can set the size of the vector at any time you like.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in order to let a vector handle the memory of the array." @user2079303 . What I meant was that if I don't dynamically allocate the array, when creating it I'd have to say something like int ar[5]. When you dynamically allocat it, I can do int* ar = new int[N], and I can pass in N as an argument to the function that creates the array. I don't know the terminology (something about run time vs compile time)

Comment: @Simon I definitely started out using a vector of vectors and then I ran into some problem so I stopped. This was 2 hours ago so I sure wish I remembered why I decided to go this route. This will teach me to take notes when programming

Comment: @FrostyStraw I'm not suggesting that you shouldn't use a dynamic array. I'm suggesting that you should let an object handle the memory of the said dynamic array instead of handling it manually. There is a class for exactly that purpose in the standard library. It's called `std::vector`. If you have problems with it, then I recommend that you try solving those problems because manual memory management will only bring you harder problems.

Comment: @user2079303 I see. I just want to be clear...when I said dynamic, I didn't mean a dynamic array in the sense that once the array is filled, it automatically resizes itself. I meant in the sense that I was creating it in the heap (which I believe is known as dynamic allocation). I know that a vector is a dynamic array.

Comment: @FrostyStraw I understood your meaning :) While vector does automatically resize itself, you don't have to use it as a dynamic array in that sense. If you never change size of the vector after it's construction, then it's simply a dynamically allocated array that manages it's own memory, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: @user2079303 so you think I should use a vector of vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was surprised to find that when I typed vertices[v]., Intellisense gave me a list of possible functions, including push_back. The reason I was surprised was because I hadn't actually created any of the vectors.

That shouldn't be surprising. Dynamic arrays are allocated at *runtime* and intellisense and all other static analyzers don't run the code, so they can never tell what the state of a variable would be at runtime. Intellisense does know that the type of `vertices[v]` is a `std::vector<int>` and it knows what member functions that type has.

But you shouldn't be surprised also because you did create the vectors. In the constructor of `Graph`.

> I realized that whenever I first call insert_edge, it tells me the size and the capacity of my array "vertices" is 0.

There is a misunderstanding here. `vertices` is a pointer. And after the constructor is run, it points to a block of memory that is a dynamic array of exactly `V` instances of `std::vector<int>` . `vertices` has no such members as `size` or `capacity`. After the construction, every `std::vector<int>` inside that dynamic array *is* empty however. Until you push in the vertices that is.

> This is obviously not working.

Your `insert_edge` seems to work fine. But you do have a problem with leaking the memory (unless you have a correct destructor that you didn't show) and a problem with incorrect copy constructor and copy assignment operator (not following the rule of three... unless you've done that but not shown it). You can fix both of those problems by using a vector of vectors instead of managing the memory manually.

> How do I Make it so that when an edge is inserted, I can look at the correct index v in the vertices array, and access the push_back function of the vector that that index of the array holds so that I can add the vertex u to the adjacency list of vertex v.

You've already figured it out:

```
vertices[v].push_back(u);
```

The same syntax is correct for vector of vectors too.

You also never set `Graph::V`, but if you use a vector of vectors, you no longer need it in the first place because it can be accessed with `vertices.size()`.

Comment: My problem was the fact that I was trying to print the adjacency lists and it wasn't printing, and it was specifically because I had not set V. That could have saved me hours of headache.

Comment: Trying to debug and look at...the actual array is very confusing when vertices is just a pointer though

Comment: @FrostyStraw yet another reason to use a vector, eh? :)

Comment: I'll certainly be using a vector of vectors if I'm asked to implement any graph algorithms in an interview

Answer (score 2):

I think you should carefully consider your choice of data structures. In the graph/algorithm community, the two standard representations of graphs are adjacency lists or adjacency matrices. See e.g.
[Standard graph representations](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/)

Please motivate why you use std::vector, and rephrase question. Linked lists (as in adjacency list representation) makes it more efficient to remove edges than your vector representation. Same goes for adjacency matrices.

Comment: I had previously used linkedlists. However, I ran into a problem when I was trying to implement breadth first search using my original graph (which used an array of std::lists) When you're looking at a particular vertex and want to look at its adjacency list (to add it to the queue), I was having trouble iterating through the list to add each vertex into the queue. Being able to access each vertex seemed easier if it was a vector storing the vertices rather than a list.

Comment: for breadth-first search, I think the preferred repr is adjacency list (O(|V|+|E|)), matrices are O('V'^2) for same problem. So maybe you should go back to using adjacency lists, they should work well if your problem does not have any special complications I am unaware of.

Comment: @ErikAlapää removing edges from a linked list is not more efficient than removing them from a vector because the order of the edges in the adjacency list does not matter. FrostyStraw is indeed using the adjacency list representation, even though they have chosen to implement the list using a vector rather than a linked-list. For most use cases, I'd say vector is more efficient as the adjacency list.

Comment: @user2079303: As you say, it depends on usage. If you process all vertices adjacent to a vertex, a vector will be faster. But it is obvious that in general, removal of e.g. one vertex is faster in a linked list than in a vector. In a std::vector, erase is linear in the number of elements after the removed element. Lists are good for erasing in the middle, vectors are not.

Comment: @ErikAlapää if the order of elements is not important - as it isn't in the case of adjacency list - then removing from a vector - from any index - is a constant time operation: If the removed index is not the last one, then move the last element to index, then `pop_back`. If the removed index is the last one, then just `pop_back`. Linked list is only more efficient at removal if the order must be maintained or if the elements are very big but not efficiently movable.

Comment: @user2079303: Good point, I was talking about the ordo for general case of removal from std::vector (in general case, you cannot assume that order is immaterial). Also, you can imagine a graph algo where adjacency lists are at some point sorted so neighbors with low edge weight come before neighbors with higher edge weight ;)

Comment: @ErikAlapää sure, I was talking about the case of adjacency list, not in general :) If you need to keep sorting when removing edges, then you probably also need to sort the adjacency list - or maintain sorting while adding edges - like in your example of weights. Then again the linked list is worse. In that case a binary search tree would probably be appropriate. But if your algorithm does need to keep the adjacency list in the same order as the edges were added while edges are removed in non-decreasing order, then linked list is clearly superior. I don't know such alrogrithm though.

Comment: @user2079303: Yes, repeated sorting is not optimal for linked lists. Like you say, a binary tree will probably be better, especially a balanced tree like the red-black trees used in std::set and std::map.